# Is it possible to use dependency injection inside a functional interface?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I know that in Jakarta you can only inject a bean instance from another bean instance. But is there a way to create a Methode-Scope or something to use in my functional interface? I need to inject a singleton inside of my functional interface.

I looked up all default scopes but they did not work for me.

Comment: What stops you from using a bean as the implementation of said functional interface? Or are you asking if you can inject into a *lambda*?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I want to use fields in the impl of the functional interface which depend on the current thread. And I want to spare RAM so I can't make it a singleton.

Comment: Then use a bean that is a factory of instances of the desired functional interface, or something like that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sounds good to me, if that is the cleanest way. I thought it would be cleaner and more threadsafe to make it a bean. I would like to mark your answer as helpful even if it is not a concrete answer to my question.